# How to handle variable name with brackets in Numpy for where function?

Tags: python, numpy, plotly-python

I am new with Numpy. I am trying to play around with dummy data and I wanted to name my variable T(s).

```
> #turning normal arrays into dataframes score_df_A = pd.DataFrame({'T(s)':score_array_A,'Domains':'2'})
```

But when I use this variable in where function like below:

```
> score_data = score_data.assign(Req = np.where(score_data.T(s) %3 > 1,
> "5","10"))
```

It gives me error:
*NameError: name 's' is not defined*

While using where functions how can we deal with variable name having brackets like ()?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a data frame, you can use this one. `score_data['T(s)']`

Comment: Its a data frame. Thank you!! It worked.

Comment: While `pandas` lets you access a column by the `df.name` syntax, that 'name' has to be a valid python variable.  It's being used as an object attribute.   The `df['name']` syntax does the same thing, but lets you use names that aren't valid variables, as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Rules for creating variables in Python:

- A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character.
- A variable name cannot start with a number.
- **A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores** (A-z, 0-9, and _ ).

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-variables/